# Android Gradle build error: undefined reference to 'main'

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, sdl-2

After succesfull compiling the code. Linking process begin and there where issue show up.

I did checked main function and it exist in code, checked cmake linking sdl and I suppose is decend. All the libs are static and I did noticed Gradle is using crtbegin_dynamic in linking process shouldn't be used crtbegin_static instead?

## Main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char commandLine[MAX_STRING_CHARS] = { 0 };

Sys_PlatformInit();

// Set the initial time base
Sys_Milliseconds();

#ifdef __APPLE__
// This is passed if we are launched by double-clicking
if (argc >= 2 && Q_strncmp(argv[1], "-psn", 4) == 0)
{
    argc = 1;
}
#endif

Sys_ParseArgs(argc, argv);

#if defined(__APPLE__) && !defined(DEDICATED)
// argv[0] would be /Users/seth/etlegacy/etl.app/Contents/MacOS
// But on OS X we want to pretend the binary path is the .app's parent
// So that way the base folder is right next to the .app allowing
{
    char     parentdir[1024];
    CFURLRef url = CFBundleCopyBundleURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle());
    if (!url)
    {
        Sys_Dialog(DT_ERROR, "A CFURL for the app bundle could not be found.", "Can't set Sys_SetBinaryPath");
        Sys_Exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    CFURLRef url2 = CFURLCreateCopyDeletingLastPathComponent(0, url);
    if (!url2 || !CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(url2, 1, (UInt8 *)parentdir, 1024))
    {
        Sys_Dialog(DT_ERROR, "CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation returned an error when finding the app bundle's parent directory.", "Can't set Sys_SetBinaryPath");
        Sys_Exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Sys_SetBinaryPath(parentdir);

    CFRelease(url);
    CFRelease(url2);
}
#else
Sys_SetBinaryPath(Sys_Dirname(argv[0]));
#endif

Sys_SetDefaultInstallPath(DEFAULT_BASEDIR); // Sys_BinaryPath() by default

// Concatenate the command line for passing to Com_Init
Sys_BuildCommandLine(argc, argv, commandLine, sizeof(commandLine));

Com_Init(commandLine);
NET_Init();

Sys_SetUpConsoleAndSignals();

#ifdef _WIN32

#ifndef DEDICATED
if (com_viewlog->integer)
{
    Sys_ShowConsoleWindow(1, qfalse);
}
#endif

Sys_Splash(qfalse);

{
    char cwd[MAX_OSPATH];
    _getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    Com_Printf("Working directory: %s\n", cwd);
}

// hide the early console since we've reached the point where we
// have a working graphics subsystems
#ifndef LEGACY_DEBUG
if (!com_dedicated->integer && !com_viewlog->integer)
{
    Sys_ShowConsoleWindow(0, qfalse);
}
#endif

#endif

Sys_GameLoop();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

## Part of cmake file:

```
target_link_libraries(etl
${CLIENT_LIBRARIES}
${SDL_LIBRARIES}
${OS_LIBRARIES} # Has to go after cURL and SDL
)
```

## Here is the build log:

```
> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:externalNativeBuildRelease
Build ui.mp.armeabi-v7a armeabi-v7a
[1/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/ui   /ui_atoms.c.o
[2/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/ui/ui_main.c.o
[3/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/ui/ui_gameinfo.c.o
[4/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/ui/ui_loadpanel.c.o
[5/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/ui/ui_parse.c.o
[6/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/ui/ui_menu.c.o
[7/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/game/bg_misc.c.o
[8/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/ui/ui_menuitem.c.o
[9/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/ui/ui_script.c.o
[10/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/ui/ui_shared.c.o
[11/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/ui/ui_syscalls.c.o
[12/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/qcommon/q_math.c.o
[13/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/qcommon/q_shared.c.o
[14/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/qcommon/q_unicode.c.o
[15/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.dir/src/game/bg_classes.c.o
[16/16] Linking C shared module legacy/ui.mp.armeabi-v7a.so
Build etl armeabi-v7a
[1/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_animation_mdm.c.o
[2/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_animation_mds.c.o
[3/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_backend.c.o
[4/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_bsp.c.o
[5/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_cmds.c.o
[6/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_cmesh.c.o
[7/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_curve.c.o
[8/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_decals.c.o
[9/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_flares.c.o
[10/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_image.c.o
[11/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_init.c.o
[12/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_light.c.o
[13/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_main.c.o
[14/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_marks.c.o
[15/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_mesh.c.o
[16/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_model.c.o
[17/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_scene.c.o
[18/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_shade.c.o
[19/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_shade_calc.c.o
[20/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_shader.c.o
[21/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_shadows.c.o
[22/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_sky.c.o
[23/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_surface.c.o
[24/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/rendererGLES/tr_world.c.o
[25/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/renderercommon/tr_common.c.o
[26/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/renderercommon/tr_font.c.o
[27/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/renderercommon/tr_image_bmp.c.o
[28/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/renderercommon/tr_image_jpg.c.o
[29/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/renderercommon/tr_image_pcx.c.o
[30/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/renderercommon/tr_image_png.c.o
[31/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/renderercommon/tr_image_tga.c.o
[32/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/renderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.dir/src/renderercommon/tr_noise.c.o
[33/123] Linking C static library librenderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.a
[34/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cm_test.c.o
[35/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cmd.c.o
[36/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cm_load.c.o
[37/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cm_patch.c.o
[38/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cm_polylib.c.o
[39/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cm_trace.c.o
[40/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cvar.c.o
[41/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/common.c.o
[42/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/files.c.o
[43/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/download.c.o
[44/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/md4.c.o
[45/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/huffman.c.o
[46/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/md5.c.o
[47/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/msg.c.o
[48/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/puff.c.o
[49/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/net_chan.c.o
[50/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/net_ip.c.o
[51/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/vm.c.o
[52/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/q_math.c.o
[53/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/q_shared.c.o
[54/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/q_unicode.c.o
[55/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/update.c.o
[56/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_avi.c.o
[57/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_bot.c.o
[58/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/vm_interpreted.c.o
[59/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_ccmds.c.o
[60/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_client.c.o
[61/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_demo.c.o
[62/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_demo_ext.c.o
[63/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_game.c.o
[64/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_init.c.o
[65/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_main.c.o
[66/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_net_chan.c.o
[67/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_snapshot.c.o
[68/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_tracker.c.o
[69/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_wallhack.c.o
[70/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_world.c.o
[71/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_ogv.c.o
[72/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_cgame.c.o
[73/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_cinematic.c.o
[74/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_console.c.o
[75/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_demo.c.o
[76/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_input.c.o
[77/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_keys.c.o
[78/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_main.c.o
[79/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_net_chan.c.o
[80/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_roq.c.o
[81/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_parse.c.o
[82/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_ui.c.o
[83/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_scrn.c.o
[84/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/qal.c.o
[85/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sys/sys_main.c.o
[88/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_codec_ogg.c.o
[89/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_codec_wav.c.o
[90/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_dma.c.o
[91/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_main.c.o
[92/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_mem.c.o
[93/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_mix.c.o
[94/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_openal.c.o
[95/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_wavelet.c.o
[96/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/botlib/be_interface.c.o
[97/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/botlib/l_memory.c.o
[98/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/botlib/l_precomp.c.o
[99/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/botlib/l_script.c.o
[100/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sys/con_log.c.o
[101/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sdl/sdl_glimp.c.o
[102/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sdl/sdl_input.c.o
[103/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sdl/sdl_snd.c.o
[104/123] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/log.cpp.o
[105/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/json_stubs.c.o
[106/123] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/i18n_main.cpp.o
[107/123] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/dictionary_manager.cpp.o
[108/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/i18n_findlocale.c.o
[109/123] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/dictionary.cpp.o
[110/123] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/iconv.cpp.o
[111/123] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/unix_file_system.cpp.o
[112/123] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/language.cpp.o
[113/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/irc/htable.c.o
[114/123] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/plural_forms.cpp.o
[115/123] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/po_parser.cpp.o
[116/123] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/tinygettext.cpp.o
[117/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/db/db_sqlite3.c.o
[118/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/irc/irc_client.c.o
[119/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/dl_main_curl.c.o
[120/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sys/sys_unix.c.o
[121/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/db/db_sql_cmds.c.o
[122/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sys/con_tty.c.o
[123/123] Linking CXX executable etl
FAILED: : && /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++  --sysroot=/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -isystem /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -Os -DNDEBUG  -ffast-math  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a --sysroot /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc -pie -fPIE CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cm_load.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cm_patch.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cm_polylib.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cm_test.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cm_trace.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cmd.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/common.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/cvar.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/download.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/files.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/huffman.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/md4.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/md5.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/msg.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/net_chan.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/net_ip.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/puff.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/q_math.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/q_shared.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/q_unicode.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/update.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/vm.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/vm_interpreted.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_bot.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_ccmds.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_client.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_demo.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_demo_ext.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_game.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_init.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_main.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_net_chan.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_snapshot.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_tracker.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_wallhack.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/server/sv_world.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_avi.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_cgame.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_cinematic.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_console.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_demo.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_input.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_keys.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_main.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_net_chan.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_ogv.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_parse.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_roq.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_scrn.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_ui.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/qal.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_adpcm.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_codec.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_codec_ogg.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_codec_wav.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_dma.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_main.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_mem.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_mix.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_openal.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/snd_wavelet.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/botlib/be_interface.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/botlib/l_memory.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/botlib/l_precomp.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/botlib/l_script.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sys/sys_main.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sys/con_log.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sdl/sdl_glimp.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sdl/sdl_input.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sdl/sdl_snd.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/json_stubs.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/i18n_main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/i18n_findlocale.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/dictionary.cpp.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/dictionary_manager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/iconv.cpp.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/language.cpp.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/log.cpp.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/plural_forms.cpp.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/po_parser.cpp.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/tinygettext.cpp.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/tinygettext/unix_file_system.cpp.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/irc/htable.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/irc/irc_client.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/qcommon/dl_main_curl.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/db/db_sqlite3.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/db/db_sql_cmds.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sys/sys_unix.c.o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sys/con_tty.c.o  -o etl  /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/libvorbisfile.a /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/libogg.a /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/libvorbis.a /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/libcurl.a /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/libz.a /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/libminizip.a librenderer_opengl1_armeabi-v7a.a /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/libSDL2main.a /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/libSDL2.a /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/libGLESv1_CM.so /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/libjpeg.a -l'm' -latomic -lm "/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a" && :
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o:crtbegin.c:function _start: error: undefined reference to 'main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

> Task :app:externalNativeBuildRelease FAILED
17 actionable tasks: 15 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

I want to make it link properly so I can move forward with my build.

Comment: `SDL_main.h` redefines `main` as `SDL_main` for some platforms, android included. Is it java-less build? Take a look at https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/fbce19db4e53/docs/README-android.md and `android-project` directory in SDL sources.

Answer (score 0):

The C file that contains **main()** should be one of the sources of the **etl** target, not of one of the libraries.

Comment: This is where main function is
    [85/123] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/sys/sys_main.c

Comment: OK, I didn't see that on my phone screen. If your **sys_main.c** `#include "SDL_main.h"`, then @keltar [is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53937505/android-gradle-build-error-undefined-reference-to-main/53941737?noredirect=1#comment94721606_53937505). The SDL library expects you to build a JNI shared lib instead of an executable.

Comment: Yes but now can I link static libs to shared one? Here is a log https://pastebin.com/KM43UGed

Comment: It looks as if you didn't define `target_link_libraries` for **etl_lib**.

Comment: Should I use target_link_libraries(etl etl-lib) or target_link_libraries(etl-lib another-lib)  @Alex Cohn ? Because the 2nd one gives me undefined reference to main again :)

Comment: I would expect `target_link_libraries(etl_lib
${CLIENT_LIBRARIES}
${SDL_LIBRARIES}
${OS_LIBRARIES} # Has to go after cURL and SDL
)`. For Android, you should not build the **etl** executable.

Comment: Ok so I had to make some changes in few cmake files and this what came out I know how to fix those atm but weird part is that vorbis link should work out of the box @Alex Cohn https://pastebin.com/iqYcTzY3

Answer (score 0):

So after fixing all those undefined reference errors I did hitted a wall there still some to manage but I am not sure how to manage them.

There are 2 files tr_init.c and tr_shade.c which are/were throwing those errors
I kinda did fixed those in tr_init.c

## tr_init.c

## Before

```
if (qglLockArraysEXT)
{
primitives = 2;
}

Ren_Print("compiled vertex arrays: %s\n", enablestrings[qglLockArraysEXT != 0]);
```

## Afrer

```
if (&qglLockArraysEXT)
{
primitives = 2;
}

Ren_Print("compiled vertex arrays: %s\n", enablestrings[&qglLockArraysEXT != 0]);
```

## tr_shade.c

```
if (qglLockArraysEXT)
{
qglLockArraysEXT(0, input->numVertexes);
Ren_LogComment("glLockArraysEXT\n");
}

if (qglUnlockArraysEXT)
{
qglUnlockArraysEXT();
Ren_LogComment("glUnlockArraysEXT\n");
}
```

Here are errors

```
/home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/rendererGLES/tr_shade.c:819: error: undefined reference to 'glLockArraysEXT'
/home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/rendererGLES/tr_shade.c:1429: error: undefined reference to 'glUnlockArraysEXT'
/home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/rendererGLES/tr_shade.c:1493: error: undefined reference to 'glLockArraysEXT'
/home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/rendererGLES/tr_shade.c:1493: error: undefined reference to 'glUnlockArraysEXT'
/home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/rendererGLES/tr_shade.c:1604: error: undefined reference to 'glLockArraysEXT'
/home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/rendererGLES/tr_shade.c:1604: error: undefined reference to 'glUnlockArraysEXT'
/home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/rendererGLES/tr_shade.c:1666: error: undefined reference to 'glLockArraysEXT'
/home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/rendererGLES/tr_shade.c:1666: error: undefined reference to 'glUnlockArraysEXT'
```

And what is most important line does not respond to those references
1st reference point to 201 line in file

Comment: Ok looks like it does not support this extension so I commented them out